# Can't see source code in VTune with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, intel-vtune

I am trying to profile OpenCV code using Intel's VTune.

The source code does not show up when I double click on OpenCV functions in VTune. Only the assembly will show up.  Non OpenCV functions show me the source code.

When I go to the platform tab, the OpenCV function calls show up graphically on the timeline.

**How do I look into the source code of OpenCV in VTune?**

I built OpenCV from source. I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and am using OpenCV 3.4.